# Wav file does not converted to Flac Using libflac.a

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to convert my recorded wave file to the flac file. I am using [this](http://8byte8.com/blog/2012/07/libflac-for-ios/) tutorial to do that. Get the LibFlac Project from [here](https://github.com/jhurt/FLACiOS), And after build that i get `flacios.framwork` and `libFLACiOS.a`.

I added both thing in my iOS project but i get error that said flacios.faramework does not found. I dont know why is that bcoz its there hall time. So i have just copied flacios.framework's Header file and add it to my project

Than i have used [wav_to_flac](https://github.com/jhurt/wav_to_flac/blob/master/wav_to_flac.c) files to convert the wave file to flac And used this code to do that:

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[searchPaths objectAtIndex:0],@"tmp"];

    NSString *flacFile = documentPath;
    NSString *waveFile = recorderFilePath;

    NSLog(@"flacFile : %@",flacFile);
    NSLog(@"recorderFilePath : %@",recorderFilePath);

    const char *wave_file = [waveFile UTF8String];
    const char *flac_file = [flacFile UTF8String];

    int interval_seconds = 30;
    char** flac_files = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * 1024);

    int conversionResult = convertWavToFlac(wave_file, flac_file, interval_seconds, flac_files);

    NSLog(@"conversionResult : %i",conversionResult);
```

My wave file log said :

`recorderFilePath : /var/mobile/Applications/C5A86F04-A6A2-44EA-81A9-7AD1F36AAE5D/Documents/MyAudioMemo.wav`

And my flac file log :

`flacFile : /var/mobile/Applications/C5A86F04-A6A2-44EA-81A9-7AD1F36AAE5D/Documents/tmp`

But i got this error at the end :

`writing to new flac file /var/mobile/Applications/C5A86F04-A6A2-44EA-81A9-7AD1F36AAE5D/Documents/tmp.flac
Assertion failed: (encoder->protected_->state == FLAC__STREAM_ENCODER_OK), function FLAC__stream_encoder_process_interleaved, file /Users/dilipmanek/Desktop/FLACiOS-no-ogg/libFLAC/src/libFLAC/stream_encoder.c, line 2040.`

Does anybody have worked on this than plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I faced the same error, and after a few hours searching I found a solution.

When you record the wav file, using the following setting and try to convert it again.

```
    recorderSettingsDict =[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],AVFormatIDKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:16000.0],AVSampleRateKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                       [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                       nil];
```